# How to extend inetOrgPerson object class in OpenLDAP with attributes used by an Active Directory user

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have an application that works with Active Directory and depends certain attributes on the user objectClass.  I would like to add a schema for use with OpenLDAP so I can create an use user accounts in OpenLDAP with the same code that works with Active Directory today.  I've created the following schema that extends inetOrgPerson, but in attempting to validate and convert it to an ldif file, slaptest responds with

> line 11 attributetype: Syntax not found: "1.2.840.113556.1.4.906"

The problem line seems to be on the Large Integer syntax used by Active Directory.  OpenLDAP only includes the Integer syntax (1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27), so how do I define a new syntax for Large Integer?

```
attributetype ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.750 NAME 'groupType'
   SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27' SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype ( 1.3.114.7.4.2.0.33 NAME 'memberOf'
    SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26' )

attributetype ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.656 NAME 'userPrincipalName'
    SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15' )

attributetype ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.52 NAME 'lastLogon'
    SYNTAX '1.2.840.113556.1.4.906' )

attributetype ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.159 NAME 'accountExpires'
    SYNTAX '1.2.840.113556.1.4.906' )

attributetype ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.96 NAME 'pwdLastSet'
    SYNTAX '1.2.840.113556.1.4.906' )

attributetype ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.221 NAME 'sAMAccountName'
    SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15' )

attributetype ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.8 NAME 'userAccountControl'
    SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27' )

attributetype ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.90 NAME 'unicodePwd'
    SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.40' )

objectclass ( 1.2.840.113556.1.5.9 NAME 'user'
        DESC 'a user'
        SUP inetOrgPerson STRUCTURAL
        MUST ( cn )
        MAY ( userPassword $ memberOf $ userPrincipalName $ distinguishedName $ lastLogon $ accountExpires $ pwdLastSet $ sAMAccountName $ userAccountControl $ unicodePwd ) )

objectclass ( 1.2.840.113556.1.5.8 NAME 'group'
        DESC 'a group of users'
        SUP top STRUCTURAL
        MUST ( groupType $ cn )
        MAY ( member ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

see this, LDAP Syntaxes supported

http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/apa/types.html#syntaxes

try: 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.38

Answer (score 0):

1.2.840.113556.1.4.906 is the [Large Integer syntax (also Integer8 and several other names) used by Active Directory](http://www.rlmueller.net/Integer8Attributes.htm) and there is no equivalent syntax within most other LDAP Server implementations.

The attributes you show in the LDIF (lastLogon, pwdLastSet and accountExpires) are actually dates which are incompatible with the Integer syntax used in most other LDAP Server Implementations when you are adding values.

The GeneralizedTime (1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.24) used by most LDAP server implementations is not the same values as used in Large Integer syntax.

However, the situation you are in will be difficult to solve as if the application is specifically querying the schema or adding values to an attribute using the "Large Integer syntax".

We have some documentation on [Large Integer Dates](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LargeInteger%20Date)

I would suggest you ask your Application vendor if they can support other LDAP implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I found this equivalence, didn't test it though.

```
OID value: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.906

OID description:
Encoded as 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 but guaranteed to support 64-bit numbers.
```

https://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.2.840.113556.1.4.906.html

My schema config:

```
# Microsoft AD olcAttributeTypes
# https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/UserPrincipalName
# https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/SAMAccountType
# https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/UnicodePwd
# https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/PwdLastSet
dn: cn=schema, cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAttributeTypes
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.656
  NAME 'userPrincipalName'
  DESC 'MSDN Active Directory UPN'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15'
  SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.221
  NAME 'sAMAccountName'
  DESC 'MSDN Windows SAM Account Name'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
  SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15'
  SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.90
  NAME 'unicodePwd'
  DESC 'MSDN Active Directory unicodePwd'
  EQUALITY octetStringMatch
  SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.40'
  SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.96
  NAME 'pwdLastSet'
  DESC 'MSDN Active Directory pwdLastSet'
  EQUALITY integerMatch
  SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27'
  SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.750
  NAME 'groupType'
  DESC 'MSDN Active Directory groupType'
  SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27'
  SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.52
  NAME 'lastLogon'
  DESC 'MSDN Active Directory lastLogon'
  EQUALITY integerMatch
  SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27'
  SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.159
  NAME 'accountExpires'
  DESC 'MSDN Active Directory accountExpires'
  EQUALITY integerMatch
  SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27'
  SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.2.840.113556.1.4.8
  NAME 'userAccountControl'
  DESC 'MSDN Active Directory userAccountControl'
  EQUALITY integerMatch
  SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27'
  SINGLE-VALUE )
```